# ASP.NET C# - A Real-Time Notifications Method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asmx, webmethod

Do you think this is a bad way to retrieve notifications?
This WebMethod will be called each 10 seconds by JavaScript. Is there any better way of doing this? If so please elaborate. Thank you.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int[] GetNotifications()
{
    int[] Notifications = new int[3]{0, 0, 0};
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        string UserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        Notifications[0] = Notification.GetAll(UserName, false).Count;
        Notifications[1] = Message.GetAll(UserName, false).Count;
        Notifications[2] = Friendship.GetFriends(UserName, true).Count;
    }
    return Notifications;
}
```

Comment: Look into Comet or reverse AJAX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) async signaling library for ASP.NET.

Comment: Could you please take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119103/signalr-refuses-to-work

Comment: SignalR is the best and fastest solution. Thanks.