# SignalR refuses to work

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, signalr

## Global.asax:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapConnection<myconnection>("echo", "echo/{*operation}");
}
```

## myconnection.cs

```
    public class myconnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override Task OnReceivedAsync(string clientId, string data)
        {
            // Broadcast data to all clients
            return Connection.Broadcast(data);
        }
    }
```

## ~/Pages/Messages.aspx

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var connection = $.connection('echo');

        connection.received(function (data) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
        });

        connection.start();

        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            connection.send($('#msg').val());
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" id="msg" />
<input type="button" id="broadcast" value="broadcast" />

<ul id="messages">
</ul>
```

## ERROR:

SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call .start() before .send()

## What I tried so far:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

Both solutions (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq) did not fix my issue.
Any idea(s)? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you properly configure the url to the `echo` script:

```
var connection = $.connection('<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/echo") %>');
```

Since you are inside the `~/Pages` folder using `echo` is incorrect because your routing expects `/echo` or `/appname/echo` if the application is hosted inside a virtual directory.